# how to get all subdirectories that has specific folder name in php?

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory

I find out that I can get all subdirectories of the folder with below code in php

```
$address = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);
```

and put it in the $address.

How can I add one more criteria and say if the subdirectory has the 'tmp' folder inside  it, then put it in the $address ?

Comment: for clarification: do you want /path/to in address or /path/to/tmp. The "it" in "put it in the $address" is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @wikinevis does in mean `/path/to` is not valid because it has `tmp` in the path ? because `path/to/tmp` also show that `path/to/` has folder in it  .....  Can up update your answer with sample output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `RecursiveFilterIterator`

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, 
        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$address = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new TmpRecursiveFilterIterator($dir), 
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST, 
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);


foreach($address as $dir) {
    echo $dir,PHP_EOL;
}
```

Class Used

```
class TmpRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        $file = $this->current();
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            return is_dir("$file/tmp");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 is totally correct (if not even making this more little as it needs to). I'm not 100% okay with this code per sé but I very much like this style. First of all any kind of `FilterIterator` is okay, so is `RecursiveFilterIterator`. Also using functions from PHP's standard lib *inside* the object abstraction (here: `is_dir`) is totally valid. Especially as SplFileInfo is part of the Spl which is the re-incarnation of Standard Php Library (SPL). Yay! So what else can I say good about this? Variable usage! Well done, PHP has COW so just use variable like here with `$file`. This is all well +1!

Answer (score 3):

You probably can add the criteria by creating yourself a `FilterIterator` that checks for a subdirectory. The following usage example demonstrates this to list folders I have under git.

`$address` is what you have in your question already, the filter is just added around:

```
$filtered = new SubDirFilter($address, '.git');

foreach ($filtered as $file) {
    echo $filtered->getSubPathname(), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Artax
CgiHttpKernel
CgiHttpKernel/vendor/silex/silex
...
composer
composer-setup
CVBacklog
...
```

And what not. This filter-iterator used is relatively straight forward, for each entry it's checked whether it has that subdiretory or not. It is important that you have the `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` enabled for this (which you have) otherwise you will get duplicate results (expressing the same directory):

```
class SubDirFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $subDir;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $subDir) {
        $this->subDir = $subDir;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept() {
        return is_dir($this->current() . "/" . $this->subDir);
    }
}
```