# How to get an unknown web directory name?

Tags: php

I have a web root directory which is setup like this:

```
apps_unknown_dir  
    |__ mylife.php
.htaccess
index.html
get-app-dir-name.php
```

The problem is that the application directory [apps_unknown_dir] name is periodically or randomly gets changed.  I would like to have a code into the file “get-app-dir-name.php” that will echo the new apps unknown directory name when run.

How can I go about getting the apps unknown directory name?

Comment: Are you executing from within `mylife.php`?

Comment: I willbe executing from "get-app-dir-name.php.

Comment: `randomly gets changed` by who, what? why? if its for protecting files from direct access, your doing it wrong. Cant you store the new foldername somewhere, is a kinda expensive operation scanning for the directory on every page load.

Comment: I will be executing from "get-app-dir-name.php.  The "get-app-dir-name.php" is included into the index.php which will then define a constant for the "apps_unknown_dir".

Comment: XY problem detected - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You shouldn't ever need to know that directory.

Comment: @Danack perhaps more like the abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz problem ;p

Comment: I know it's kinda expensive to rescanning, I am trying to figure a better way.

Comment: I added an answer, but it still does scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate over folders in that directory, looking for one that's not on known-list, or that has `mylife.php` file in it.

You may do it like in answers to that question: [how to get all subdirectories that has specific folder name in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389012/how-to-get-all-subdirectories-that-has-specific-folder-name-in-php)

Comment: I think this should do it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head you could try this: (*warning untested code*)

```
$knownFolders = array('folderIKnow', 'folderKnown', 'anotherFolderNameIKnow');
$unknown = array_diff(glob("/folder/to/app/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR), $knownFolders);
echo $unknown;
```

So you have a list of known folders, then scan the folder for all directories, see the difference between the scan and the white-list.

Comment: This did it! `$__path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'*';

foreach (glob($__path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."mylife.php") as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "\n";  
}
`