# How to return instances of a specific folder name and its paths?

Tags: php, directory

I took a look at recursive searching in PHP [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769514/get-folders-with-php-glob-unlimited-levels-deep), and it's really helped my understanding of what I want to do. However, I'm hitting a minor roadblock.

What I want to do is use this recursive search to return the path of a specific folder name that is in multiple locations. Once that folder name is found, it would execute another function. This would continue until all folders with that name are found.

**I have some code from a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389012/how-to-get-all-subdirectories-that-has-specific-folder-name-in-php) as a base, but I'm a little confused on how to phrase it as such to "look" for a certain folder name. What is the best way to do that?**

Comment: See the comments in http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php They are pretty useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exemple that works (in other words, there is probably a more elegant way to do it):

```
function myfunction($param) {
    echo $param . PHP_EOL;
}

$path = realpath('/myrootpath');
$target = 'myfolder';

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
                                         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
                                         RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    if (preg_match('~^.+/' . $target .'(?=/\.$)~', $object, $match))    
        myfunction($match[0]);
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Now I need to get the other function I made to work properly, but that's another question.